# Proving the statement $\mathbb P(AB') = \mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P(AB)$

Tags: probability

This is a question about probability theory, considering that $B'$ is the complement of an event $B$.

Why can we say that $\mathbb P(AB') = \mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P(AB)$? I can get why we should subtract $\mathbb P(AB)$ - since $AB$ is also part of $B$ - but I can't get why we are not considering $\mathbb P(B')$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^\prime) = \emptyset $ and $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^\prime) = A$

so $\mathbb P(A) =\mathbb P(A \cap B) +\mathbb P(A\cap B^\prime)$

and thus $\mathbb P(A\cap B^\prime)=\mathbb P(A) -\mathbb P(A\cap B)$.

You can also say $\mathbb P(A\cap B^\prime)=\mathbb P(B^\prime) -\mathbb P(A^\prime\cap B^\prime)$ if you wish, using similar arguments

Answer (score 2):

$AB$ is the part of $A$ with $B$.

By subtracting $\mathbb P(AB)$ from $\mathbb P(A), $ we get the part of $A$ without $B$, i.e., $\mathbb P(AB')$.